# PHP echo display outside the div

Tags: php, html, echo, display

My project is to display a **calendar** with the number of the day on top of a "card" from the bootstrap library.

Under the number of the day I display the name of the day, what I want is just to echo a number or character on the right of the name of the day which come from a function.

The function return a value from a SQL query.

**Screenshots:**

[The php with html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acBxa.png)

[My function in php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Snx.png)

[My app in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiAen.png)

The code:

```
<?php 
session_start();

include 'Cadre.php';
$date = new DateTime('2018-01-01');
$idEleve = 1;
$idClasse = 1;
try

{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

function devoir($result, $idClasse, $idEleve, $bdd) {
    try         
    {
        $req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT `idMatiere` FROM devoir WHERE `idEleve` = :idEleve AND `dateDevoir` = :date_devoir OR `idClasse` = :id_classe AND `dateDevoir` = :date_devoir");
        $req->execute(array(
            ':id_classe' => $idClasse,
            ':idEleve' => $idEleve,
            ':date_devoir' => $result));
            while($devoir = $req->fetch()){
                if($devoir['idMatiere']== 1){
                    echo $devoir['idMatiere'];
                };
            }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
            die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>

<br>
<h1 class="display-4">Agenda</h1><p class="lead"> <?php echo $date->format('F'); ?></p>
<br>
<?php
        echo '
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1"></div> ';
        while(date_format($date, 'd') <= '30'){
            if($date->format('l') != 'Saturday' AND $date->format('l') != 'Sunday'){
                $result = $date->format('Y-m-d');
                echo ' 
                    <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="https://google.com">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">'.date_format($date, 'd').'</h3> 
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">'. $date->format('l').devoir($result, $idClasse, $idEleve, $bdd).'</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a></div>';
            }
            else{
                echo '</div><br>';
                echo '
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-1"></div>';
            }
            $date->modify('+1 day');
        }
        echo '</div>
            <br>';
    ?>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Mois précédent</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Mois courrant</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Mois suivant</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-7"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks a lot for taking the time to read and sorry for my english <3

Comment: dont use echo inside functions, use return instead

Comment: the truth has been spoken by @rtfm you are not returning the value you are using `echo` the value instead.

Comment: Thank youuu so much it works !

Comment: The answer: **return $devoir['idMatiere'];**

Answer (score 0):

remove the `h6` element and replace it with `span` inside `h3` 
since the heading elements like H3 , H6 display as block .

```
<div class="card-body">
   <h3 class="card-title">'.date_format($date, 'd').' <span> class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">'. $date->f
ormat('l'). devoir($result, $idClasse, $idEleve, $bdd).'</span>
   </h3>
</div>
```